# Flutter build and Xcode archive confusion

Tags: flutter

I know this may sound stupid but I am quite confused:

Per the Flutter docs, in order to release an iOS app, we are required to first run

`flutter build ios`

which triggers xcode to build

Then, in `Xcode`, we have to select the generic ios device and run `Product > Archive`.
Archive also produces a build, and seems to build everything from scratch.

So what is the purpose of running `flutter build` in the release flow ?

**EDIT:**

From my observation, `flutter build` generates an up-to-date version of the Generated.xconfig. If you pass arguments to `flutter build` these will go in there. Then the archive will also trigger a build, but based on this config.

Answer (score 0):

`flutter build` make a `Project -> ios -> Flutter -> App.framework`.

And `App.framework` is your flutter program.

Comment: So you’re saying flutter build creates the app.framework and archive builds the archive that uses this app.framework?

Comment: Product > Archive also compiles App.framework, so I still don't know what flutter build is used for

Comment: From my experience, yes. Check your App.framework date.

Comment: both `flutter build` and `Product -> Archive` update the App.framework

Comment: I think it is just a means to reflect the latest flutter code.. Xcode script [/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build] does the same. So I am using scripts like this when debugging code dependent on iOS. [if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build
fi]

Comment: The thing is you can pass options to `flutter build` like  `-bundle-sksl-path` but since `Product -> Archive` seems to override the build, how to I get an archive with this option?

Comment: Edit a [$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh] file. Or set a [$BUNDLE_SKSL_PATH]